# Change background image opacity, without affecting max-height, max-width

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, opacity

I've ran into a problem, I have a background image I would like to make an opacity of 0.35, I saw that by using the image as a tag, with absolute property you can cheat the fact that CSS doesnt have a background image opacity selector. I also have max width set on my other images, so when i tried that, all my images went back to their original gigantic size. Here is my code, any answer would help, i reverted back to my original code with max width images.

```
     html {
    background-image: url(*image url*);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}
img {
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
}
.navBar {
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: background images do not go on the html tag. Change it to the body tag.

Also, not sure why you'd want to change the opacity of an image that has nothing behind it?

Comment: Of course background images can go on the html tag - moving it to the body makes no difference.

Comment: its a dark image, im going for a dark theme

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 html {
        background-image: url(*image url*);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;

    }
    body {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.53);
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are very likely to be unhelpful for future visitors and even the OP himself. Consider editing your answer to contain explaination with the code.